# What is this word for a person more knowledgable than an aficionado?

Tags: nouns, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

A friend told me a new word for a person with a higher more sophisticated knowledge than an aficionado. It sounds like "koount ah shent ie". My best guess of the spelling is "countashenti", but that has not led me to the correct word. What is the correct spelling?

Answer (score 20):

Could it be *cognoscenti*?

> co·gno·scen·ti
>   ˌkänyəˈSHentē,ˌkäɡnəˈSHentē
>   noun
>   people who are considered to be especially well informed about a particular subject.

Comment: An everyday pronunciation is kah-no-SEN-tee.

Comment: Oh, man. I've been pronouncing that G for *ever*. :(

Comment: @Davo There are a few words like this where the G is silent, e.g. *intaglio*.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie [In-TA-lio]? that's new to me! I've always pronounced the 'g'... >_<

Comment: Aack - Cagliostro, too. I'm ruined!

Comment: @marcellothearcane Silent G :)  It's from Italian.

Comment: [How to pronounce cognoscenti](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/cognoscenti).

Comment: The Brits seem to mostly pronounce the G, going by both the link @MikeJRamsey56 gave and the [OED's audio pronunciation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/35908) (paywalled, sorry). I'm from the US, and I'm not sure I've ever heard the word pronounced, only seen it in print. In the "American" pronunciation it sounds like it's the *gn* of *gnocchi* (which I learned to pronounce thanks to Curious George and Chef Pisghetti's cat).

Comment: As cognoscenti is plural, it cannot strictly be an answer to the OP's question, although I imagine it's the word he was given. So is the singular, cognoscente, ever used in English? It's listed in Collins, but I've never heard it used.

Comment: Wouldn't it be gender-specific if it was still in common Italian usage? I do agree with @David that it's plural and so can't apply to an individual, in the opposite way that plural _dilletante_ are collectively _dilettanti_. As I was taught it, the first bit is pronounced very similarly to the Spanish/Mexican _conio_ (lol).

Comment: @Davo ... applies to almost every borrowed Italian word with a gl or gn : seraglio, imbroglio, intaglio, sfogliatelle, bologna, bolognese, lasagne, consiglieire... and so forth. That said: once English steals a word, it's ours to pronounce as we please (until some do-gooder turns Calcutta back into Kolkata and Peking to Beijing).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for *cognoscenti* this is usually applied in the context of a group of community rather than in the singular to an individual.

It is usually used for fields related to arts and culture and also has implications in terms of elite  social status and connections and can imply insider knowledge and influence as well as technical or academic expertise.

Form your definition *connoisseur* may also apply. This tends to focus more on appreciation and knowledge of a subject.

However both terms tend to imply that any 'expertise' lies in the consumption, analysis or appreciation of cultural products rather than expertise in their production.

Both terms also tend to apply more to things which are rare, expensive of associated with high social status.

Comment: 'Cognoscenti' has already been given, and the attempted pronunciation rules out 'conoisseur'.